# Split 100 million row table into multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance

I have a SQL Server 2012 database. There is one table that has more than 100 million rows. I want to split that table into multiple similar tables, with 1 million rows in each table. What is the best way to achieve this quickly?

I have tried paging, but it takes too much time, and sometimes gives an out of memory exception in SSMS.

There are 12 columns. 11 are `varchar` and one is `datetime`. There is no primary key available in the table, and no `ID` column. It is a very old database table that we migrated to SQL Server 2012.

Its size is around 20 GB. There are no indexes available. I don't want more complexity, I just need to split it.

Comment: What types of queries are you running against this table? This would help more other people so they can make appropriate suggestions. You might be benefited from common partitioning or vertical partitioning or just indexing. And what is the edition of SQL-Server (Standard, Enterprise, etc.)? It would also help to add the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to split this 100 million row table into any number of tables, even without it having any indexes. Now, you might could do it purely in T-SQL but that would require loading each of the split tables via individual insert statements in a transaction, and that can be a bit heavy on the tran log, especially if splitting to tables of 2 million rows each.
But, thanks to the totally awesome awesomeness of the fully streamed API for Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs), a small (and relatively simple) C# / VB.Net (or any .Net language) app can handle this, and do so without using more than 1 row's worth of memory (on the app side; buffer pool on the DB is what it is), and do so using a minimally-logged operation! The trick is to:

- call a stored procedure that accepts a TVP for the rows to move, and
- pass the rows into the TVP by setting the `SqlParameter` value to a method that returns `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`. This will allow for incrementally moving through a `SqlDataReader` that is reading the source records.
  Using this method, the size of the source table shouldn't matter: splitting a 1 billion row table should only require more time (and the obvious disk space required to duplicate the table).

### Database Objects

**First:** You need a User-Defined Table Type

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.SplitTable AS TABLE
(
   CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   StringField01 VARCHAR(500) NULL,
   StringField02 VARCHAR(500) NULL,
   ...
   StringField10 VARCHAR(500) NULL,
   StringField11 VARCHAR(500) NULL
);
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::[dbo].[SplitTable] TO [user_or_role];
GO
```

**Second:** Use the UDTT as an input param to an import proc. Hence "Tabled-Valued Parameter" (TVP)

```
-- DROP PROCEDURE dbo.ImportChunk
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ImportChunk (
   @TableNumber   INT,
   @SplitTable    dbo.SplitTable READONLY
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @CurrentTableName sysname;

BEGIN TRY

   -- Empty TVPs are not allowed, and can't send DbNull.Value when using
   -- IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>, so send in a single-row with a field to test that would
   -- otherwise never have that value. Only need to test 1 row as real sets of rows
   -- won't have this value so no need to test the whole set.
   IF ((SELECT TOP (1) [CreateDate] FROM @SplitTable) = CONVERT(DATETIME, 0))
   BEGIN
      RETURN;
   END;

   BEGIN TRAN;

   SET @CurrentTableName = N'dbo.SplitTableName_'
                           + RIGHT(N'000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @TableNumber), 4);
   PRINT 'CurrentTableName: ' + @CurrentTableName;

   SET @SQL = N'CREATE TABLE '
              + @CurrentTableName
              + N' (
CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
StringField01 VARCHAR(500) NULL,
StringField02 VARCHAR(500) NULL,
...
StringField10 VARCHAR(500) NULL,
StringField11 VARCHAR(500) NULL
);';

   EXEC(@SQL);

   -- Use a SYNONYM as we are dealing with dynamic table names which requires Dynamic SQL
   -- but the TVP is a table variable and cannot be referenced in Dynamic SQL. However,
   -- a SYNONYM can be created in Dynamic SQL and is a consistent object name that can
   -- be used in the static / main portion of this code where the TVP can be used.
   -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx (CREATE SYNONYM)
   SET @SQL = N'CREATE SYNONYM CurrentImportTable FOR '
              + @CurrentTableName;

   EXEC(@SQL);

   -- The WITH (TABLOCK) hint is required for this query to be considered minimally logged.
   -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx (INSERT)
   INSERT INTO CurrentImportTable WITH (TABLOCK)
      (CreateDate, StringField01, StringField02, --...,
      StringField10, StringField11)
      SELECT tmp.CreateDate,
             tmp.StringField01,
             tmp.StringField02,
             ...
             tmp.StringField10,
             tmp.StringField11
      FROM   @SplitTable tmp;

   DROP SYNONYM CurrentImportTable; -- Clean up.

   COMMIT TRAN;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

   IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
   END;

   DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(4000);
   SET @Message = ERROR_MESSAGE();
   RAISERROR(@Message, 16, 1);

END CATCH;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.ImportData TO [user_or_role];
```

### C# Code

**Third:** Open a `SqlDataReader` to a simple select on the table in question (essentially a cursor). The trick is to implement a method that will

- read a set number of rows rather than until the end of the result set
- pass each row, as it is read, to the TVP

Then just call the stored procedure shown above passing in the loop counter (so we can name the new table appropriately) and the method that returns only that set number of rows via `IEnumerable`. Keep calling the procedure until there are no more records in the result set / `SqlDataReader`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace TableSplitter
{
    class Program
    {
        // these first two variables are static as their values need to be passed back to
        // the main loop but iterators (i.e. returning IEnumerable) cannot have "ref" parameters
        private static SqlDataReader _RowsToSend;
        private static int _RowsCopied;

        private static int _RowsPerSplit;

        private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> SendRows()
        {
            SqlMetaData[] _TvpSchema = new SqlMetaData[]
            {
                new SqlMetaData("CreateDate", SqlDbType.DateTime),
                new SqlMetaData("StringField01", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500),
                new SqlMetaData("StringField02", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500),
                //...
                new SqlMetaData("StringField10", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500),
                new SqlMetaData("StringField11", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500)
            };

            SqlDataRecord _DataRecord = new SqlDataRecord(_TvpSchema);
            object[] _AllFields = new object[12];

            // read a row, send a row
            for (_RowsCopied = 0; _RowsCopied < _RowsPerSplit; _RowsCopied++)
            {
                if (!_RowsToSend.Read())
                {
                    break;
                }
                _RowsToSend.GetValues(_AllFields);
                _DataRecord.SetValues(_AllFields);

                yield return _DataRecord;
            }

            if (_RowsCopied == 0)
            {
                _DataRecord.SetDateTime(0, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1));
                yield return _DataRecord;
            }
        }

        public static void SplitTable(string ConnectionString)
        {
            _RowsCopied = _RowsPerSplit; // seed value to enter the loop

            int _TableNumber = 1;

            SqlConnection _SourceConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand _SourceCommand = new SqlCommand(
                "ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED;",
                _SourceConnection);
            _SourceCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlConnection _DestinationConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand _DestinationCommand = new SqlCommand(
                "dbo.ImportChunk",
                _DestinationConnection);
            _DestinationCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter _TVParam = new SqlParameter();
            _TVParam.ParameterName = "@SplitTable";
            _TVParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            _DestinationCommand.Parameters.Add(_TVParam);

            SqlParameter _TableNumParam = new SqlParameter();
            _TableNumParam.ParameterName = "@TableNumber";
            _TableNumParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            _DestinationCommand.Parameters.Add(_TableNumParam);

            try
            {
                _SourceConnection.Open();
                _SourceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                _SourceCommand.CommandText =
                    @"SELECT CreateDate, StringField01, StringField02, --...,
                    StringField10, StringField11 FROM dbo.TableToSplit;";
                _RowsToSend = _SourceCommand.ExecuteReader();

                _DestinationConnection.Open();

                while (_RowsCopied == _RowsPerSplit)
                {
                    _TableNumParam.Value = _TableNumber;
                    _TVParam.Value = SendRows(); // method return value is streamed data

                    _DestinationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    _TableNumber++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception _Exception)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("\n\n" + _Exception.Message + "\n\n");
            }
            finally
            {
                _RowsToSend.Close();
                _DestinationConnection.Close();

                _SourceCommand.CommandText = 
                    "ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;"; // or FULL
                _SourceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                _SourceConnection.Close();
            }

            return;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch _ElapsedTime = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            _ElapsedTime.Start();

            _RowsPerSplit = 1000000;

            SplitTable("Trusted_Connection = yes; Database = Test;");

            _ElapsedTime.Stop();

            System.Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tElapsed Millseconds: {0}\n\n", 
                                      _ElapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I ran this on my laptop with a sample table consisting of:

- 5 fields: 1 `DATETIME` and the other 4 are `VARCHAR`
- 3 million rows
- 205 GB

I ran it several times and it took about 19 - 24 seconds to split into 3 tables of 1 million rows each.

Answer (score 1):

Create your destination sub-tables in advance.  Decide how many rows you would like in each and the criteria you will apply for deciding which new table a row will go into.  This would be an *excellent* opportunity to add a primary key to the new tables, even if it is only a surrogate `IDENTITY()` column, and cluster like rows together e.g. all from this year in one table and those from last year in a different table.

```
Define a cursor
Loop throgh the cursor
    decide which table the row goes to according to your rules
    begin a transaction
    insert the old values into the chosen sub-table
    delete WHERE CURRENT OF your_cursor_name
    commit the transaction
```

Books online covers the `where current of` syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189835%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).  SQL Server's internal cursor pointers will ensure only the one row the cursor's pointing to will be deleted and not any duplicates.

I delete from the existing table to ensure you can restart in the event of failure.  If you can mark each row as having been processed this would be preferable.  Make sure you take a backup before you start executing.  I specify a transaction to ensure the data is "clean" in the event of failure.  Beginning and commiting a transaction can be expensive.  You may choose to process, say, 10,000 rows in a single transaction before committing.

Make sure you get [CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184746.aspx) right.

Depending on your hardware's capability you may want to do this in batches rather than fill the cursor with all 100M rows in one go.